# What's wrong with this proof by contradiction (Session 3.3 of How to prove it)?

Tags: proof-verification, logic

I am reading *How to prove it* and doing the exercise in session 3.3.

Theorem: *For every real number $x$, $x^2 \geq 0$*.

What's wrong with the following proof of the theorem?

Proof. Suppose not. Then for every real number $x$, $x^2 \lt 0$. In particular, plugging in $x = 3$ we would get $9 \lt 0$, which is clearly false. This contradiction shows that for every number $x$, $x^2 \geq 0$.

This proof makes sense to me but why it is incorrect?

Comment: The negation of an existential quantifier is a universal quantifier.

Comment: You CAN'T put $x = 3$. The negation of the theorem is: *there exists* a real number $x$ such that $x^{2} <0$.

Comment: To construct a proof by contradiction, you need to prove the absurdity of the statement "There exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2 < 0$.

Comment: I think you make a logic error in line 3, which might have been said this way instead:: "Proof. Suppose not. Then there is at least one number x, such that..."

Comment: As an example of why this is logic is wrong, note that by removing the squaring everywhere, the exact same "proof" could be used to show "for every real number $x, x \ge 0$". This is a useful method for understanding where you went wrong: see if you can use the same technique to "prove" something you know is false, and then figure out where it stopped making sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since The negation of $\forall x(x^2 \geq 0)$ is $\exists x(x^2 \lt0)$, the sentence " Then for every real number $x$, $x^2 \lt 0$" is therefore incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the negation of an existential quantifier is a universal quantifier. Hence, $\neg(\forall x: p(x))$ is not $\forall x:\neg p(x)$ but $\exists x:\neg p(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If your theorem is false, then it is *not* the case that *for every real number,* $x, x^2\ge 0$.

It doesn't follow that if the theorem is false, *all* squares are negative. For the theorem to be false, we need only one counter-example. We don't need $x$ to be less than zero for *all* real numbers. Your contradiction says too much. So checking one square and showing it is positive, won't help you. You need to show that they *all* are positive. Perhaps a proof by induction?

What I've said isn't anything not already in the answers or comments.